# Silex : connexion session

Tags: php, silex

I would to connecte user existing in database by using sessions

```
<?php
//...
$app->match('/',function(Application $app, Request $req)  {
    $app['session']->set('login', $req->query->get('login'));
    $app['session']->set('password', $req->query->get('password'));
    $app['session']->set('login2', $req->query->get('login2'));
    $app['session']->set('password2', $req->query->get('password2'));

    // Je stocke les infos du fomulaire dans session.

    $login=$app['session']->get('login');
    $pass=$app['session']->get('password');



    if ($app['db']->executeQuery('SELECT login FROM users WHERE login="'.$login.'"') == 1){
      if($mdp = $app['db']->executeQuery('SELECT pass FROM users WHERE login="'.$login.'" AND pass="'.$pass.'"') == 1){
        return $app->redirect('/signup'); // test
      } 
    }
    else {
      return $app->redirect('/');
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('login.twig', array('users' => $result));
});
```

Twig code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Créer un utilisateur</title>
        <style>
             p  {
                display:inline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Connectez vous</h1>
        <form method="post">

            <p>Joueur1 </p><input type="text" name="login"
                   placeholder="choisissez un pseudo" required>
            <p>Mot de passe </p><input type="password" name="password"
                   placeholder="choisissez un mot de passe" required>
                   <br>
                   <p>Joueur2 </p><input type="text" name="login2"
                   placeholder="choisissez un pseudo" required>
            <p>Mot de passe </p><input type="password" name="password2"
                   placeholder="choisissez un mot de passe" required>

            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="connexion">
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

The result is that it's redirecting me to /signup without let user identifying  himself.

Comment: On your controller your render the *login.twig* template with an inexistent variable, where does the *$result* gets populated? Also, I fail to see what's your problem and your goal, could you explain more precisely?

Comment: I would let user connect.. If ID or password are wrong I redirect him to sign up page. But here It direct automaticly to /signup. I use sessions to save id and pass but I thing there is a problem when saving also